# Want to sum some fields and leave others alone SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a query that results in a field of varying lengths (6, 8, 10, ...) and respective counts as seen below:

```
"region","repeatLength","count"
"promoter","6","272387"
"promoter","8","86929"
"promoter","10","28337"
"promoter","12","8873"
"promoter","14","3080"
"promoter","16","1098"
"promoter","18","475"
"promoter","20","206"
"promoter","22","133"
"promoter","24","75"
"promoter","26","42"
"promoter","28","32"
"promoter","30","16"
"promoter","32","6"
"promoter","34","9"
```

This table was generated by this call:

```
select region, repeatLength, count(*) as count 
from alignedRepeats
group by region, repeatLength;
```

I would like to be able to condense these results so that repeat lengths < 18 are intact, but repeat lengths >= 18 are aggregated into one row by summing the count field.  Is this possible to do in a single sql query without making temporary tables and unioning them?

Sorry if this is a simple question, I am an SQL newbie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select region, 
    case when repeatLength >= 18 then ">=18" else repeatLength end as repeatLength, 
    count(*) as count  
from alignedRepeats 
group by region, 
    case when repeatLength >= 18 then ">=18" else repeatLength end;
```

Comment: +1 Might want to give the consolidated repeatLength column a name.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to create a temporary table. You can use a union, though:

```
select region, repeatLength, 1 as Colname
from alignedRepeats
where repeatLength < 18
union
select region, repeatLength, count(*)
from alignedRepeats
where repeatLength >= 18
group by region, repeatLength;
```

Not sure what you want the last field to contain, though, hence '1 as Colname'

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer (tested)

```
select
    region,
    repeatLength,
    count(*) as count
from
    alignedRepeats
where
    repeatLength < 18
group by
    region,
    repeatLength
union
select
    region,
    999,
    count(*)
from
    alignedRepeats
where
    repeatLength >= 18
group by
    region
```

Note: Using "999" to indicated the aggregate row.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce another field, highGroup, which is 0 if repeatlength <= 18, else 1, then group on the highGroupfield in an outer query.